# How to get the first element from a child lookup in aggregation - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find all the docs from `groupUserRoleSchema` with a specific `$match` condition in the child. I'm getting the expected result, but the child `application` inside `groupSchema` is coming as an array.
I just need the first element from the application array as an object. How to convert this application into a single object.

These are my models

```html
const groupUserRoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    group: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'group'
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }
});

const groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    application: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'application'
    }
});
```

Here is my aggregate condition.

```html
groupUserRoleModel.aggregate([
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "groups",    //must be PHYSICAL collection name
                localField: "group",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "group",
              }
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "users",    
                localField: "user",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "user",
              }
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "applications",    
                localField: "group.application",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "group.application",
              }
            },
            {
              $addFields: {
                group: {
                  $arrayElemAt: ["$group", 0],
                },
                user: {
                  $arrayElemAt: ["$user", 0],
                }
              },
            },
            {
              $match: {
                "user.email_id": requestHeaders.user_email
              },
            }
          ]);
```

Here the $lookup `group.application` is coming as an array. Instead i need it as an object.

Below added is the current output screen-shot

[image]

Here is the expected output screen-shot

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please provide an example of current output and expected output. Looks like you can use `$first`.

Comment: @nimrodserok I have updated the question with the screen-shots, Please see.

Answer (score 1):

A alternative is re-writing the main object return, and merge the fields.
The lookup field, gonna use the `$arrayElemAt` attribute at position 0, with the combination of the root element `'$$ROOT'`.

```
const result = await groupUserRoleModel.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
              "user.email_id": requestHeaders.user_email //The Match Query
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'groups', // The collection name
            localField: 'group',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'group', // Gonna be a group
          },
        },
        {
          // Lookup returns a array, so get the first once it is a _id search
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              $mergeObjects: [ // merge the object
                '$$ROOT',// Get base object
                {
                  store: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ['$group', 0], //Get first elemnt
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ]);
```